# Apache cordova: data storage in local database

Tags: apache, cordova

We are developing an cross platform app using Visual Studio 2015 and apache cordova. We need large number of data to be stored in the local database. We are currently having problems with storing all the data being migrated into the local database. What is the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "local database", I assume you're talking about a WebSQL database?

The size limit of WebSQL DBs is platform dependent; for example, iOS gives you 50Mb, but Android offers 200+Mb depending on Android version. See [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/) for storage capacities across platforms.

If you require a larger storage capacity than this, consider using something like [this plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) which allows you to use a native SQLite database with unlimited capacity.